# qual atalho uso para ele formatar a estrutura ali?

Tags: c++

olá! meus codigos as vezes pela rapidez da digitação ficam deestruturados(bagunçados), como faço pra voltar? uso VS

tipo: /* int variavel;

```
   cin >> ;

   switch (expressao){

        case:
  break;


case2:
        break;


default:
  }
```

Comment: Olá  Fabricio e boas-vindas. É importante **[edit]**, usando um titulo descritivo do problema e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva o que precisa. **Não delete e não repita a pergunta**, basta editar e aguardar o processo de reabertura. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.